# How to connect to the VPN automatically on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

If I use `nm-connection-editor` and check "Automatically connect to VPN" then WiFi doesn't start. If I uncheck it, WiFi starts but then I have to start VPN manually.

In terminal I can see this warnings when checking the box and save

```
(nm-connection-editor:2052): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:37:51.050: GtkGrid does not have a child property called expand

(nm-connection-editor:2052): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:37:51.055: GtkGrid does not have a child property called fill
```

Edit1: Screenshoots:
[Connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsxY7.png)
[Auto VPN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z8lO.png)

Edit 2:
*Switching to TCP mode seems to stop disconnection*

Comment: You have to import your .ovpn file into NetworkManager, and then when in nm-connection-editor, select "Automatically connect to VPN" as you have been, and then popup the button just to the right and select your imported VPN connection profile.

Comment: That is exactly how I did it. After restart Wired is off, When connect to WiFi, VPN is connected automatic. BUT I have to click on connect

Comment: You want to run wired, or wireless? Which connection profile did you enable VPN? Which "connect" to your refer to?

Comment: Ubuntu is running in ViritualBox on my Mac so Wired, Is possible change to Wireless?

Comment: Oh, we're running in VB? What host? What is "Network Adapter, Connected via" set to? You also didn't answer my question about which "connect" button you refer to.

Comment: Host is Macbook Pro, and "Connect" is under "Wired off". But there is another problem, VPN stops after 10-15 min.

Comment: Let me fully understand... Mac OS host... VB trying wireless connection... is the Mac on a wired connection? Is the VB wireless connection going to a USB dongle, or using the Mac's internal wireless?

Comment: Mac is Wireless and No USB Dongle, Guest was Wired "out of the box"

Comment: Well, I'm still confused. Edit your question and show me a screenshot of the VB Network settings panel, and the "Connect" under "Wired off".

Comment: What does your host use for configuring it's network firewall, is it `iptables`? Also can ya edit your question with a **_scrubbed_** (substitute data, consistently, that you believe is _sensitive_) version of both your VPN configs as well as the configs within the Guest OS's `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` directory? And what `iptables` rule-set are you using within the Guest OS? Adding these to your question will help with sorting out the intermittent disconnects and other connection _gremlins_ that seem to be cropping-up.

Answer (score 1):

The build I have that's closest related to yours uses the connection profiles found under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`

Some connection profile settings that may be of use; documentation pulled from [nm-settings](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/unstable/nm-settings.html) from `developer.gnome.org`

```
autoconnect-priority <int32>
```

> The autoconnect priority. If the connection is set to autoconnect, connections with higher priority will be preferred. Defaults to 0. The higher number means higher priority.

```
autoconnect-slaves   <int32>
```

> Whether or not slaves of this connection should be automatically brought up when NetworkManager activates this connection. This only has a real effect for master connections. The properties "autoconnect", "autoconnect-priority" and "autoconnect-retries" are unrelated to this setting. The permitted values are: 0: leave slave connections untouched, 1: activate all the slave connections with this connection, -1: default. If -1 (default) is set, global connection.autoconnect-slaves is read to determine the real value. If it is default as well, this fallbacks to 0.

```
master <string>
```

> Interface name of the master device or UUID of the master connection.

```
secondaries <array of strings>
```

> List of connection UUIDs that should be activated when the base connection itself is activated. Currently only VPN connections are supported.

---

Putting this together with manuals that maybe reviewed via `man NetworkManager`, `man NetworkManager.conf`, and `man nm-settings`, here's the portions of my AP's connection profile, eg. *`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/WiFI_AP`*, that are relevant...

```
[connection]
id=WiFI_AP
uuid=aaaa-0000-aaaa-0000
type=wifi
autoconnect=true
autoconnect-priority=9000
permissions=
secondaries=deadbeef-d3ad-b33f-dead-be33e3f;
autoconnect-slaves=1
vpn.timeout=120
# ... more connection config blocks...
```

... the VPN connection profile did **not** require modification (in other-words I only included `master` documentation references in-case your system requires it for some reason), instead I had to copy it's `uuid` into the above `secondaries` list, in this example that would mean the *`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/VPN_Client`* looks something like...

```
[connection]
id=VPN_Client
uuid=deadbeef-d3ad-b33f-dead-be33e3f
type=vpn
permissions=
secondaries=
# ... more connection config blocks...
```

> Note, `lists` for connection profiles are space separated   strings, and end with a semicolon **`;`**

I've tried turning off/of my WiFi as well as reboots and full shutdowns and the connection resumes as desired!

If ya run into problems, eg `sudo systemctl status NetworkManager` is logging read errors or file not found, then ya may want to move the VPN configurations and certs into a directory that isn't an encrypted home directory, or set a longer `vpn.timeout`, or log-in faster.

---

Reading through the comments of your [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1144816/172838) @Per-ÅkeFranklind, sounds like the network *shape* is a bit like...

```
    [Mac_wlan]    # Host hardware
       | ^
       v |
    [VMs_vEth]    # Virtualized interface
       | ^
       v |
    [VPN_tun0]    # Within VM of Ubuntu
```

> Names are just placeholders because the question doesn't include it explicitly, so some *translation* will be required yet again.
>
> And no LaTeX/Mathjax support here so can't really make the above any *prettier*.

... if so then you've got a firewall at the Host level *`Mac_wlan`* that'll need to be configured to allow traffic forwarded out of *`VMs_vEth`*, then within the VMs instance of *`VMs_vEth`* (which may be renamed within the Guest OS) the firewall there will have to be configured to allow traffic forwarded out of the *`VPN_tun0`* interface, and each layer should allow established (and in some cases related) connections the other direction.

If ya edit your question with more info, scrubbed of course of anything sensitive, for example the guest OS's `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` connection profiles, and what your VPN configs sorta look like, it will help those that wish to provide ya with a more complete answer.